# Postgresql - Is calling a stored procedure in a trigger possible?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger

I would like to call a stored procedure using a trigger in Postgresql. Is it possible?

Here is an example:

```
create table foo(n int primary key, n1 int);     

create or replace procedure set_column_value(value int)
language plpgsql
:as $$
begin
 update foo
 set n1 = id
commit;
end;$$
```

The trigger would be something like:
After insert or update on foo, call the stored procedure set_column_value(new.n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a trigger needs to call a trigger *function*. But there is nothing that keeps you from writing a PL/pgSQL trigger function that `CALL`s the procedure of your liking.

It may be confusing that `CREATE TRIGGER` allows this syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ... EXECUTE { PROCEDURE | FUNCTION } ...
```

However, this is a syntactical leftover from the time before PostgreSQL had procedures. Back then, the only allowed syntax was `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`, even though it called a trigger *function*. With the advent of procedures, this became rather odd, so the new and now preferred syntax `EXECUTE FUNCTION` was introduced, but `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` is still allowed for compatibility reasons. Still, you can only call a function, not a procedure.

Comment: But, you won't be able to invoke COMMIT in such a CALL;

Comment: Hey @laurenz , Postgresql docs shows that you can call a procedure. It states on the syntax: `EXECUTE { FUNCTION | PROCEDURE } function_name ( arguments )` was this related to a specific version? Thanks: doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Laurenz!